# Set a default value on Jquery progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this Jquery plugin

http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php#

and I just want to create a default value, in the HTML, when the page loads.... I don't need a click action or any animation...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the default value when you initialize the progress bar -

```
$("#pb1").progressBar(65); // Will have 65% as the default value

// Will have 95% as default value with additional options.
$("#pb4").progressBar(95, { showText: false, barImage: 'images/progressbg_red.gif'} );
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why that wasn't obvious to me last night :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var defaultProgress = $("#progressbarVal").text();
    $("#YourID").progressBar(defaultProgress);
};
```

And a HTML div with the value:

```
<div id="progressbarVal">40</div>
```